# Loki: Ingester high memory usage

Tags: grafana-loki

Please advise on the use of memory with the Loki - Ingester component.

I have the following setup: loki distributed v2.6.1 installed through the official helm chart in K8s.

The number of promtail clients is ~1000 hosts. Each of them generates a large load. About 5 million chunks (see screenshot below)

[image]

The number of loki_log_messages_total is 235 million per day.

My problem is that the ingester is using about 140 GB of RAM per day, and the memory consumption keeps increasing. I want to understand if this is normal behavior or can I somehow reduce memory usage through config? Tried to adjust various parameters myself, in particular chunk_idle_period and max_chunk_age. But no matter what values I set, memory consumption is still at 100+ GB.

I also tried to reduce the number of labels on the client side, at the moment the labels are as follows:

[image]

Here is my config:

```html
auth_enabled: false
chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s
compactor:
  retention_enabled: true
  shared_store: s3
  working_directory: /var/loki/compactor
distributor:
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: memberlist
frontend:
  compress_responses: true
  log_queries_longer_than: 5s
  tail_proxy_url: http://loki-distributed-querier:3100
frontend_worker:
  frontend_address: loki-distributed-query-frontend:9095
  grpc_client_config:
    max_recv_msg_size: 167772160
    max_send_msg_size: 167772160
ingester:
  autoforget_unhealthy: true
  chunk_block_size: 262144
  chunk_encoding: snappy
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  lifecycler:
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: memberlist
      replication_factor: 1
  max_chunk_age: 15m
  max_transfer_retries: 0
  wal:
    enabled: false
ingester_client:
  grpc_client_config:
    max_recv_msg_size: 167772160
    max_send_msg_size: 167772160
limits_config:
  cardinality_limit: 500000
  enforce_metric_name: false
  ingestion_burst_size_mb: 300
  ingestion_rate_mb: 150
  max_cache_freshness_per_query: 10m
  max_entries_limit_per_query: 1000000
  max_global_streams_per_user: 5000000
  max_label_name_length: 1024
  max_label_names_per_series: 300
  max_label_value_length: 8096
  max_query_series: 250000
  per_stream_rate_limit: 150M
  per_stream_rate_limit_burst: 300M
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
  retention_period: 72h
  split_queries_by_interval: 30m
memberlist:
  join_members:
  - loki-distributed-memberlist
querier:
  engine:
    timeout: 5m
  query_timeout: 5m
query_range:
  align_queries_with_step: true
  cache_results: true
  max_retries: 5
  results_cache:
    cache:
      enable_fifocache: true
      fifocache:
        max_size_items: 1024
        ttl: 24h
query_scheduler:
  grpc_client_config:
    max_recv_msg_size: 167772160
    max_send_msg_size: 167772160
runtime_config:
  file: /var/loki-distributed-runtime/runtime.yaml
schema_config:
  configs:
  - from: "2022-09-07"
    index:
      period: 24h
      prefix: loki_index_
    object_store: aws
    schema: v12
    store: boltdb-shipper
server:
  grpc_server_max_recv_msg_size: 167772160
  grpc_server_max_send_msg_size: 167772160
  http_listen_port: 3100
  http_server_idle_timeout: 300s
  http_server_read_timeout: 300s
  http_server_write_timeout: 300s
storage_config:
  aws:
    s3: https:/....
    s3forcepathstyle: true
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /var/loki/boltdb_shipper/index
    cache_location: /var/loki/boltdb_shipper/cache
    shared_store: s3
  index_cache_validity: 5m
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s
```

In documentation I have not found any examples or information for heavy loads, so I decided to ask the community. I will be very grateful for help.